# The Current State of Mongo DB 2013

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, nosql

I've been using MongoDB (via MongoLab) for all of my web app development and have been loving it's ease of use and integration with AngularJS. Recently however, a lot of people I work with who were at one time evangelists of MongoDB are starting to back away. One of my SYSADMINS specifically said, "don't use Mongo, we are backing away from it...mainly because we can never be certain that data actually writes to disk".

I found this to be a major bummer. Since then I have checked out CouchDB which I find very cool. It still uses JSON, and also provides a GUI (Futon) and a basic CLI. This puzzles me because Mongo seemingly has a robust following, user base, and community. Before I actually start developing and migrating my projects from Mongo to Couch I wanted to get the pulse of what dev are using to get an idea if this is just FUD or an actual concern.

Comment: Instead of wondering when it writes to disk, [why not specify it](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#when-does-mongodb-write-updates-to-disk).

Comment: CouchDB is no different in this regard - it accepts the write, it fsyncs. If the system crashes between the two the data may not be written to disk. If your sysadmins are RDBMS types they probably won't like you using any non-transactional noSQL type system.

Comment: CoreyOgbun & @AsyaKamsky Good to know, and this is EXACTLY why I posted this question.

Comment: @user2365841 TOTAL idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> don't use Mongo, we are backing away from it...mainly because we can never be certain that data actually writes to disk

Hmm, jounalled acked writes?

> It still uses JSON

JSON ain't great, also BSON is a higher level version of JSON with a more representative notation allowing for the storing and representation of objects which JSON cannot.

> and also provides a GUI (Futon) and a basic CLI.

There is a basic CLI and you can get, oh-so-many, GUIs for MongoDB if that's what floats your boat.

> Before I actually start developing and migrating my projects from Mongo to Couch I wanted to get the pulse of what dev are using to get an idea if this is just FUD or an actual concern.

One note, which I found when I used CouchDB, you will find it uses a lot more space maintaining not only the JSON but also the versioning mechanism it has in place. Not only that but its Map Reduce is just not as good as MongoDBs aggregation framework (frankly).

I should stress, however, that I only used it a small amount before I ditched it.

Comment: @Sammayae thanks for your input! After posting this I realized that a lot of the concerns that were presented to me were very opinionated. I'm going to stick with MongoDB as it turns out to be a lot of FUD. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB focus on speed, but this doesn't mean that you can never sure if the data was written to disk.

In the [connection object](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html), you can specify options to tune the write concerns. The more important ones are:

- *w*: Represents how many machines the mongo client should wait. If you set this to *N*, the mongo client will wait for *N* machines to write this data to disk. This option is useful if you have [replica sets](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/).
- *j*: Represents if the mongo client should wait the operation to be put on the journal.

### EDIT:

I put links to the Python driver, because Python is a very high level language, but these options shall be available in every MongoDB driver.

### EDIT2:

As stated by @asya-kamsky, even if you choose *w > 0*, MongoDB will only update the [mmapped file](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#what-are-memory-mapped-files) and the changes will only be fsync'ed to disk after the [syncDelay](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#when-does-mongodb-write-updates-to-disk).

Anyway, if you need to improve [durability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durability), you should use replica sets to decrease the [single point of failure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure).

Comment: This is not technically accurate.  If you use w:N then it will wait for N servers to write it into mmapped file (in RAM) so it may not be fsync'ed to disk for up to 100ms.  If you specify j:1 then it will wait till journal is flushed to disk.  Note that you can use both w:N as well as j:1 - j will apply to the primary.

Comment: @asya-kamsky: you are right, I forgot about the _mmap_ feature.